# Matlab postset method sample fails

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to call a function right after I change some properties of an object in Matlab. I went to the documentation and found this sample code:

```
classdef PropListener < handle
   properties (SetObservable, AbortSet)
      PropOne
      PropTwo
   end
   methods
      function obj = PropListener(evtobj)
         if nargin > 0
            addlistener(evtobj,'PropOne','PostSet',@PropListener.handlePropEvents);
            addlistener(evtobj,'PropTwo','PostSet',@PropListener.handlePropEvents);
         end
      end
   end
   methods (Static)
      function handlePropEvents(src,evnt)
         switch src.Name
            case 'PropOne'
               display('I was here!');
            case 'PropTwo'
               display('I was here too!');
         end
      end
   end
end
```

I saved this into a file, went to the console and tryed

```
test1=PropListener
test1.PropOne=1
```

and it doesn't show the "I was here!" message. The rest works perfectly.

After some debuging, I found 2 problems:

1 - It calls the constructor method without arguments, therefore

```
if(argin>0)
```

returns always false and it never creates the listeners.

2 - If I remove the if/end structure, when I call the constructor

```
test1 = PropListener
```

Matlab returns "Error using PropListener (line 9)
Not enough input arguments."

(line 9 is the line with the following statement)

```
addlistener(evtobj,'PropOne','PostSet',@PropListener.handlePropEvents);
```

Now, if I remove the whole constructor method and call

```
addlistener(evtobj,'PropOne','PostSet',@PropListener.handlePropEvents);
```

on the command line, everything works, but I would have to remember to call that line while writing my scripts, and I don't want to run that risk.

I'd like to know how could I implement this postset feature, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,